# Splitting a black box rational function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus, rational-functions

Suppose I can evaluate a black box rational function $f(\vec{x})$. For the purposes of the explanation, let me take an example I can actually write down
\begin{equation}
f(\vec{x})=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}{(x_1+x_2)(x_2+x_3)(x_3+x_4)(x_4+x_1)}.
\end{equation}
I know some theoretical properties of this black-box function, e.g.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x_1\rightarrow -x_2} (x_1+x_2)f(\vec{x})\neq 0, \quad \lim_{x_3\rightarrow -x_4} (x_3+x_4)f(\vec{x})\neq 0, \quad \lim_{x_1\rightarrow -x_2} (x_1+x_2)\lim_{x_3\rightarrow -x_4} (x_3+x_4) f(\vec{x})=0.
\end{equation}
These can be verified for the specific form I provided above. I am interested in defining $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that $f=f_1+f_2$ and
\begin{align}
\lim_{x_1\rightarrow -x_2} (x_1+x_2)f_1(\vec{x})\neq 0, \quad \lim_{x_3\rightarrow -x_4} (x_3+x_4)f_1(\vec{x})= 0, \\
\lim_{x_1\rightarrow -x_2} (x_1+x_2)f_2(\vec{x})= 0, \quad \lim_{x_3\rightarrow -x_4} (x_3+x_4)f_1(\vec{x})\neq 0.
\end{align}
One way to do this is to define
\begin{equation}
f_1(\vec{x})=f(\vec{x})-\frac{1}{x_3+x_4}\lim_{x_3\rightarrow -x_4}(x_3+x_4)f(\vec{x}), \quad
f_2(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{x_3+x_4}\lim_{x_3\rightarrow -x_4}(x_3+x_4)f(\vec{x}),
\end{equation}
but this requires to take a limit, which I would rather avoid. Is there any other way I can achieve this separation (for example, by multiplying $f$ by two other known rational function that sum up to one)?